# Add scores grid game JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add 10 points when blue box goes into brown box.

I tried to set score = 0 and points to add = 10 but it doesn't work.

I alert '+10 points' and it shows me the alert so I guess the problem is the DOM ?!?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

```js
    let moveCounter = 0;
    let score = 0;
    let obs = 10;


    document.getElementById('score').textContent = '0';
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

    for (var i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
      var square = document.createElement("div");
      square.className = 'square';
      square.id = 'square' + i;
      grid.appendChild(square);
    }

    var obstacles = [];

    while (obstacles.length < 10) {
      var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
      if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
        obstacles.push(randomIndex);

        var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
        $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob")
      }
    }

    var playerOne = [];
    while (playerOne.length < 1) {
      var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
      if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
        playerOne.push(randomIndex);

        var drawPone = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
        $(drawPone).addClass("p-0")
      }
    }

    var addPoints = $('#score');



    $('#button_right').on('click', function() {
      if ($(".p-0").hasClass("ob")) {
        alert('add +10 points !!!')
        addPoints.text( parseInt(addPoints.text()) + obs );
      }
      moveCounter += 1;
      
      if ($(".p-0").hasClass("ob")) {
      
      }

      $pOne = $('.p-0')
      $pOneNext = $pOne.next();
      $pOne.removeClass('p-0');
      $pOneNext.addClass('p-0');
    });
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.ob {
 background-color: brown;
 }

.p-0 {
 background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="grid-box">
</div>

<div class="move">

<button id="button_right">right</button><br>

</div>
<div id="score">
</div>
```

Thank you very much! I am new to JavaScript/ JQuery 
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should move your test at the end of your function, because actually it alerts "+10 points" when you leave the brown box, not when entering it. Your current problem is that `addPoints` is a jQuery object representing the DOM element, not a number, you should use `addPoints.text( parseInt(addPoints.text()) + obs );` with `parseInt` because the value is in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the HTML inside of the div with id "score". 
Selecting the css element using `$("#id")` retrieves the DOM element and not its contents so adding the score directly to it has no consequences.

What you want to do is: update the score variable and then set the HTML inside the div to the score value.
So instead of just:

```
addPoints += obs
```

you should

```
score += obs
addPoints.html(score)
```